# While using the Object.defineProperties in JavaScript I am getting as ' undefined' on newly defined property .How to fix it..?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, object-properties, object-property

```js
const object1 = {
    firstName : 'Shashidhar',
    lastName : 'B M ',
    rollNo : 5678,
    rank : 23456

}

Object.defineProperties(object1,{
    property1 : {
    results : 'selected'
    }
});


console.log(object1.property1)
console.log(object1.firstName);
```

expected output

```
selected
shashidhar
```

actual output

```
undefined
shashidhar
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `defineProperties` correctly? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties Consider using `value` instead of `results`?

Comment: I think, per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), you need to set `value`. `results` doesn't seem to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `value` rather than `results` to specify the property's value:

```js
const object1 = {
    firstName : 'Shashidhar',
    lastName : 'B M ',
    rollNo : 5678,
    rank : 23456
}

Object.defineProperties(object1,{
    property1 : {
    value : 'selected'
    }
});


console.log(object1.property1)
console.log(object1.firstName);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) on MDN.